# ¿Cuál es el peligro o problema de convertir un nvarchar hacia uniqueidentifier?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

Tenemos una base de datos las cuales en las columnas cuando tiene que crear identificadores se crean con tipo de datos en `nvarchar(100)`.

Se quisiera hacer una conversion hacia `uniqueidentifier`.

¿Cuál es el peligro en hacer esto? Teniendo en cuenta que nuestra base de datos cada vez que importa datos o crea nuevos, esta crea muchas tablas (en total hay mas de 2 millones de tablas y van en crecimiento)

Gracias por la ayuda de ante mano

Comment: @sstan, si es SQL server (version 2008 y 2012)

Comment: ¿2 millones de tablas? ¿Será que son 2 millones de registros en la tabla? ¿Cómo se crean los identificadores? ¿Hay alguna consideración de diseño por la cual se decidió utilizar `nvarchar(100)`?

Answer (score 0):

Las primeras consideraciones o *problemas* serían, el tamaño, indexación (si es que actualmente existe un índice), y recuperación de registros.

1. Con el número de registros que mencionas es una razón bastante considerable para utilizar un `NVARCHAR`  como identificador único. No es lo mismo utilizar `NVARCHAR` 100 posiciones a utilizar un `BIGINT`, suponiendo que te ahorras 40 bytes por registro, finalmente es una cantidad considerable.
2. Si en algún momento deseas realizar búsquedas sobre la columna `NVARCHAR(100)` teniendo un aproximado de 2M de registros, sin duda será lenta. Si consideras la posibilidad de crear un índice, el proceso de indexación tendrá un gran impacto en el rendimiento de la base de datos.
3. El proceso para insertar un nuevo registro tendrá que recorrer los 2M de registros para saber si no ha sido utilizado ese identificador.

Talvés, lo ideal sería utilizar un `BIGINT` para evitar atacar el rendimiento del servidor, o en su caso un `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`. De hecho, si tuvieras una arquitectura distribuida esta segunda opción sería la ideal.